# Can Tor be used with Netflix or Hulu?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, plugin

I am curious as to how it would work to use Tor for Netflix or Hulu if I have paid subscriptions to both sites.

Comment: I assume you're using Tor Browser?

Comment: A USA based VPN provider or proxy will work better for this and also not put unnecessary load on the tor network.

Comment: I'm curious what your purpose for doing this would be. As Tor is meant as a location anonymity tool, what benefit do you receive for being location anonymous with a service you're signing into with your true identity? Also, Tor will likely be much too slow for streaming HD video. Not only that, but you'll also be slowing down Tor for people who may be relying on it for actual privacy. If you're looking to watch movies from a country that is blocked by Netflix, you're probably better off using a proxy, rather than Tor. Or, as others pointed out, you can try https://hola.org/ which appears to be

Comment: It is actually hola.org. I just tried it, and it worked like a charm. It took a few tries for netflix to work but it finally did.

Comment: Did you get tor browser to work with netflix? My company has blocked netflix so I have to use tor browser for other sites as well but I was wondering if its possible to watch netflix with tor.

Comment: @MacLemon that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view netflix or hulu from countries where those are not available then Hola is a better option for you. I am using this and works like a charm for this purpose.

Comment: Dear I assume you are using VPN and not Tor, is this correct?

Comment: Hola is not a VPN. You should check out www.hola.com. Tor is great for anonimizing. Hola is a great alternative for VPN. It is free and very fast. I generally use Tor, only if I need to connect from a specific country (like you need with netflix) I use hola.

Comment: Dear, I understand that. What I am asking is, are you directly connecting to Hulu site or connecting through VPN or connecting through Tor network?

Comment: I connect to Netflix (no hulu for me) through Hola, not tor, not VPN, not directly.

Comment: The question was about Tor not about other suggestions.